# Dictionary not identifying the right key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to use a dictionary of file extensions to call the right method to convert a file but the dictionary keeps calling the first key instead of the correct one. Here is the dictionary:

```
def convertirV2(fichier):
    print(Path(fichier).suffix)
    choices = {
        ".docx": conver_docs(fichier),

        ".pdf": conver_pdf(fichier),

        ".txt": conver_txt(fichier),

        ".html": conver_html(fichier),

        ".xlsx" or ".xls": conver_xls(fichier),

        ".csv": conver_csv(fichier),

        is_binary(fichier): fichier

    }
    return choices.get(Path(fichier).suffix)
```

I can confirm that I'm giving the right key (.html in this case) but it still tries to call the conver_docs method. Any idea why that is?

Comment: While constructing the dictionary you are converting the file (calling each of these conversion functions) & then returning only one. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Oh so it tries to call every function while building the dict?

Comment: When you create the dictionary, you are invoking all of the functions `conver_docs`, `conver_pdf`, etc, explicitly. The values should not be the values returned by those functions, they should be the functions themselves. change the key-value pairs to `".docx": conver_docs`, etc. Also, `".xlsx" or ".xls"` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example to illustrate the issue:

```
def foo():
    print("I'm in foo")

def bar():
    print("I'm in bar")

functions = {
    "a": foo(),
    "b": bar()
}
```

Output:

```
I'm in foo
I'm in bar
>>>
```

As part of the dictionary's construction, you explicitly invoke the functions `foo` and `bar`, because of the `()`. You'll probably want key-value pairs of strings mapping to the functions themselves, rather than the values returned by those functions when called:

```
functions = {
    "a": foo,
    "b": bar
}

functions["a"]()
```

Output:

```
I'm in foo
>>>
```

In my example, `foo` and `bar` take no parameters, but your `conver_...` functions do. To facilitate this, you would simply pass the parameter at the time at which you actually invoke the desired function:

```
choices = {
    ".docx": conver_docs,
    ".pdf": conver_pdf
    # ...
}

choices[Path(fichier).suffix](fichier)
```

In addition, `".xlsx" or ".xls": conver_xls(fichier)` doesn't do what you think it does. The expression `".xlsx" or ".xls"` will always evaluate to the single string `".xlsx"`, because in that expression the string-literal `".xlsx"` is non-empty, which means it will be treated as a "truthy" value. An `or` expression only needs one of its operands to be `True` for the entire expression to be `True`, and so, due to short-circuit evaluation, the whole expression evaluates to `".xlsx"`. This means files with the extension `".xls"` will not be considered by the dictionary. You'll have to make a separate key-value pair for `".xls"`.